# Knockout - Fetching paginated data, initial load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm building a simple paginated table view with KnockoutJS and Twitter Bootstrap. Right now I have everything working except that I can't get the initial dataset to load when the page loads. Looking at my view model, you can see that the proper data loads when "navigating" trough the customer repository via a RESTful API.

How can I get the initial data to load?

```
<script>

    var ListViewModel = function() {
        var self = this;

        window.viewModel = self;

        //Properties
        self.list = ko.observableArray();
        self.pageSize = ko.observable(20);
        self.pageIndex = ko.observable(0);
        self.itemCount = ko.observable();

        self.maxPageIndex = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            return Math.ceil(self.itemCount() / self.pageSize()) - 1;
        });

        self.allPages = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            var pages = [];
            for (i = 0; i <= self.maxPageIndex() ; i++) {
                pages.push({
                    pageNumber: (i + 1)
                });
            }
            return pages;
        });


        //navigation Functions
        self.previousPage = function () {
            if (self.pageIndex() > 0) {
                self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() - 1);
            }
            self.getItems();
        };

        self.nextPage = function () {
            if (self.pageIndex() < self.maxPageIndex()) {
                self.pageIndex(self.pageIndex() + 1);
            }
            self.getItems();
        };

        self.moveToPage = function (index) {
            self.pageIndex(index);
            self.getItems();
        };

        //API interactions
        self.getItems = function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: '/api/customer/?pageNumber='+self.pageIndex()+"&pageSize="+self.pageSize(),
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (result) {
                    self.list(result);
                }
            });
        };

        self.getTotalItemCount = function() {
          //TODO: Add call to fetch total number of customers in the database and set      it to self.itemCount property.
        };


    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        ko.applyBindings(new ListViewModel());
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Before you go further with knockout, read John Papa's articles on building SPA with knockout or check out source code for it https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change you start code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var vm =  new ListViewModel()
   vm.getItems()
   ko.applyBindings(vm)
});
```